# Supporting iOS 5 and iOS 6 in Xcode 5

Tags: ios5, ios7, ios6, xcode5, ios-universal-app

I am going to develop an iOS universal application. I want to target iOS 5,6 and 7.

I am using xCode 5 for my development. I want to know is it possible to support iOS 5,6 and iOS 7 in same app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, set the deployment target to iOS 5. You will have to make separate storyboards for iOS 5/6 and 7, and choose which to load upon startup based off of the device's OS.

Comment: Do you have any tutorials for this? I am a new on xcode.

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad you shouldn't be asking for tutorials or off site resources this makes your question off-topic for this site.